# Обработка ответа сервера vue.js и axios.js

Tags: php, vue.js, axios

В ответ на post запрос получаю ответ в виде [image: СКРИН КОНСОЛИ ХРОМА]
Теперь хочу в помощью vue.js в случае такого ответа показать сообщение на странице:

`<div v-if="success" id="vue">СООБЩЕНИЕ</div>`

```
new Vue({
  el: '#vue',
  data() {
    return {
      success: false
    }
  },

    check() {
      axios
        .post('main2.php', {
        data_1: this.data_1,
        })
        .then(response = "success" {
        this.success = true;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
})
```

Написал это условие

```
        .then(response = "success" {
        this.success = true;
```

Но это очевидно совсем не то, знаю как вывести сообщение в случае ошибки, например если сервер не доступен,

```
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.errored = true;
```

а вот как быть с конкретным ответом не пойму.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ви не правильно написали блок `then`

```
check() {
    axios
      .post('main2.php', {
      data_1: this.data_1,
      })
      .then(responce => {
        if (responce.data === 'success'){
          this.success = true
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо :) Теперь буду думать как быть с несколькими уникальными сообщениями при ответе сервера, аж мозг щекотно) Он приходит в виде: "data:"success1""success2""success3" и тут видимо надо что-то в php менять, т.к. всё в куче.

Comment: ну можно разбить и через js, но лучше будет если api будет отдавать объект с нужными полями

Answer (score 1):

```js
const API_ENDPOINT = 'https://httpbin.org/post';

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        success: false
    },
    methods: {
        async check() {
            try {
                const { data } = await axios.post(API_ENDPOINT, { data_1: 'tested' });
                console.log(data);
                this.success = true;
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        }
    }

    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <button @click="check" :disabled="success">CHECK</button>
    Status: {{ success }}
</div>
```